# Azure Redis Cache Slow log not logging anything

Tags: azure, caching, logging, azure-redis-cache

I'm trying to monitor how long queries are taking to my Azure hosted Redis cache. 
It seems the Slow log only logs queries I make through Redis-cli directly when I remote into it rather than when my client application makes any queries to it. 
I've set the slowlog to log queries slower than 0 as I want to log all queries however this doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now, the "Azure Redis Cache" service does not allow you to configure a custom slowlog setting. The default slowlog setting in use is 10 milliseconds. So, any operation that takes more than 10 milliseconds should get logged.